# Vertical Align on Grid Elements

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align my grids, so all the text appears inline with the other grids. I've managed to get it working on large screens, but when you resize the browser window it loses its vertical alignment.

I've thrown together a CodePen here too, so you can see my issue: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/qLwfs

I'm vertically aligning my grid elements like so:

```
.cover {
    height: 312px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: #F0D5C0;
}
```

Here the grid elements are vertically aligned. See how all the text blocks below the image are inline with one another.

[image]

When you resize the window though, this happens. The grid elements are no longer vertically aligned.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean when you resize you only get 1 grid item per line?  If so, that's because you've set them to take up 7 columns on small devices.  You can only fit 1 on a 12 column grid.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I've updated my post above with some images to to help explain my issue better.